# Connecting Term to a Redux dispatch Action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have created an input field with a search term which creates a request to a backend API. To summarise, two issues:

- It fetches data from my API, but it fetches ALL roles, not just ones filtered by the term.
- It does not commit to the redux store.

Please see my app, it contains simply:

This is my frontend component, which is making an action dispatch based on a search term.

```
export function SearchBarTrialRedux(props) {

    const [isExpanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);
    const [parentRef, isClickedOutside ] = useClickOutside();
    const inputRef = useRef();
    const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState("");
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [jobPostings, setjobPostings] = useState([]);
    const [noRoles, setNoRoles] = useState(false)

    const isEmpty = !jobPostings || jobPostings.length === 0;


    const expandedContainer = () => {
        setExpanded(true);
    }

    const collapseContainer = () => {
        setExpanded(false);
        setSearchQuery("");
         setLoading(false);
         setNoRoles(false);
        if (inputRef.current) inputRef.current.value = "";

      };


    useEffect(()=> {
        if(isClickedOutside)
            collapseContainer();
    }, [isClickedOutside])

    const [term, setTerm] = useState("")


    const dispatch = useDispatch();


    const changeHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        fetchAsyncRoles(dispatch, {term});
    }


    return (
    <SearchBarContainer animate = {isExpanded ? "expanded" : "collapsed"} 
                        variants={containerVariants} transition={containerTransition} ref={parentRef}>
        <SearchInputContainer>
            <SearchIconSpan>
                <SearchIcon/>
            </SearchIconSpan>
            <form onSubmit={changeHandler}>
            <SearchInput placeholder = "Search for Roles" 
                                onFocus={expandedContainer} 
                                ref={inputRef}
                                value={term}
                                onChange={(e)=> setTerm(e.target.value)}
                                />
            </form>
 </SearchBarContainer>
```

And my jobsearchSlice

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { publicRequest } from "../requestMethods";

export const fetchAsyncRoles = async (dispatch, term) => {
  dispatch(searchStart());
  try {
    const res = await publicRequest.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/role/titlerole?title=${term}`);
    dispatch(searchSuccess(res.data));
    console.log(res.data)
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch(searchFailure());
  }
};


const jobsearchSlice = createSlice({
  name: "jobsearchSlice",
  initialState: {
    isFetching: false,
    roles: [],
    error: false,
  },
  reducers: {
    searchStart: (state) => {
      state.isFetching = true;
    },
    searchSuccess: (state, action) => {
      state.isFetching = false;
      state.roles = action.payload;
    },
    searchFailure: (state) => {
      state.isFetching = false;
      state.error = true;
    },
  },
});

export const { searchStart, searchSuccess, searchFailure } = jobsearchSlice.actions;
export default jobsearchSlice.reducer;
```

As stated, it does create and fetch this data. This does commit it to the store under the roles key, which is great! That's what I want, however it is not filtering. E.g If we look at a role specifically like Data Scientist:
https://gyazo.com/ca4c2b142771edd060a7563b4200adf8

I should be getting just 1 key, Data Scientist.

Looking at the backend of the console.log(res), I can see that it appears my term isn't properly coming through and filtering my roles :

responseURL: "http://localhost:5000/api/role/titlerole?title=[object%20Object]"

But if I log the term, it does come through exactly as input.

What's wrong, what am I doing and how should I solve this term flowing through to filter my req?
I can confirm that if I do this on postman it works...

https://gyazo.com/10f2946c1a3807370b4792c06292b557

Comment: In `fetchAsyncRoles(dispatch, {term});` you are passing an object, so when the request URL is constructed `${term}` becomes `[object Object]`. Just pass the string and you should be good.

Comment: Thanks Yuri! Correxct this works. How would I map out the state to frontend?